# String generic constraints as computed key

Tags: typescript, generics

I want to define a generic type, where I can pass a string value as the generic argument, and use it to define a key on the type, e.g.:

```js
const foo: MyType<'hello'> = {
  hello: "Goodbye",  // this key is required
  bar: 2
}
```

I tried defining it as the following:

```js
const type MyType<T extends string> = {
  [key: T]: string,
  bar: number,
};
```

However I get an error, saying that `An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'`, even though in this context, it must be a string. Is there some different syntax for this issue? Or is this limitation of typescript at present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
const foo: MyType<'hello'> = {
  hello: "Goodbye",  // this key is required
  bar: 2
}

type MyType<K extends string> = {
    bar: number;
} & Record<K, string>
```